# Appropriate phpDocumentor tags for MVC framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpdoc

I'm just new to using PhpDocumentor...

If I have a project named foo and am using zend framework in modular architecture:

Modules
   -module_test
     -controller
        -indexController
     -views
        -indexView
     -models
        -index_model

What phpdoc tags would be good to use?

Right now I'm thinking of (for instance the indexController.php)

```
/**
 * @author some author
 * @category module_test
 * @package controllers
 * @copyright http://rainbowriders.dk Rainbow Riders ApS
 * @version 1.0
 */
```

would that be sufficient?
Many thanks for any reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework has some standards that it defines as required for inline documentation so you can use those as guidelines.  Not all Zend Framework classes even use all of the tags so use you can omit some at your discretion.

See [Coding Standards - Inline Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standards.inline-documentation) on ZF docs page.

**Files**

*Every file that contains PHP code must have a docblock at the top of the file that contains these phpDocumentor tags at a minimum:*

```
/**
* Short description for file
*
* Long description for file (if any)...
*
* LICENSE: Some license information
*
* @category   Zend
* @package    Zend_Magic
* @subpackage Wand
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
* @license    http://framework.zend.com/license   BSD License
* @version    $Id:$
* @link       http://framework.zend.com/package/PackageName
* @since      File available since Release 1.5.0
*/
```

**Classes**

*Every class must have a docblock that contains these phpDocumentor tags at a minimum:*

```
/**
* Short description for class
*
* Long description for class (if any)...
*
* @category   Zend
* @package    Zend_Magic
* @subpackage Wand
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
* @license    http://framework.zend.com/license   BSD License
* @version    Release: @package_version@
* @link       http://framework.zend.com/package/PackageName
* @since      Class available since Release 1.5.0
* @deprecated Class deprecated in Release 2.0.0
*/
```

**Functions**

*Every function, including object methods, must have a docblock that contains at a minimum:*

```
A description of the function

All of the arguments

All of the possible return values
```

Answer (score 0):

The following was created by PHPDocumenter plugin for VIM. I have been using it for a long time and I think it's quite sufficient. Just fyi.

```
/**
 * Class name 
 * 
 * @uses parent class
 * @package 
 * @version $id$
 * @copyright 1997-2005 The PHP Group
 * @author my name <my@php.net> 
 * @license PHP Version 3.0 {@link http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt}
 */
```